Repairing/replacing subfloor in a closet
In our fairly old modular/manufactured home (purchased with land), we had a water heater crap out in a BIG way, got some significant water damage, and now I’m working on repairing/replacing subfloor in short order, so I can get a new water heater in the closet. And now I’m seeking some help for strategy. Here’s the gist…

There is a 24 x 30 inch area of particle board subfloor, where the water heater goes, that is SEVERELY warped. At least that much needs to be replaced (or leveled and reinforced AT THE VERY LEAST).
The joists appear to be a standard 16 inches apart.
There is a (non-load-bearing) wall that divides the closet from the bedroom. That wall appears NOT to be on the joist.
I would like to replace the severely warped section in the closet where the water heater goes (and possibly beyond that, into the bedroom).

In the accompanying pics:

Closet subfloor from above, showing fresh-air intake for gas water heater in center.
2 & 3. Photos of joists and fresh-air intake from below the house.
Closet subfloor from above again, showing approximate location of 16-inch joists.

I’ve got two possible solutions:
A. Slightly jerry-rigged version: planing/sanding/leveling subfloor and slapping plywood on top to reinforce.
B. What I presume to be a better solution: remove damaged subfloor and replace with plywood.
So, now I have some questions…

Would I be better off simply slapping some plywood on top of existing subfloor, after planing/sanding/leveling?
If I replace the subfloor, how do I get under this wall that appears to be off of the joist?
It also looks like the bottom plate for that wall is in rough shape. So, should I remove subfloor, knock out bottom plate, and replace it all?
Anything I’m missing or being an idiot about?

Thanks in advance for any and all input!





The sub floor is rip out and replace.  The bottom plate test with a pointy thing and push in by hand.  Going in more that a 1/8 by hand is a replace job also.  Less than 1/8 inch just spray some bleach on it.

@crip659 Got it. Thanks!
